# Ubuntu 20.04 won't boot (filesystem has errors), fsck didn't fix, recovery mode fails

Tags: filesystem, data-recovery, fsck, recovery-mode, inode

In late November 2020, I installed Ubuntu 20.04 on an external hard drive,
and I was using it with no significant problems.  Then when I tried to boot
it and log in (via the usual way) on Dec 21, it failed.  Instead of giving
me the usual login screen, it displayed messages about problems with inodes.
I turned off the computer, and tried to boot again.  This time, it came up
with a screen that displayed the following output:

```
[   0.159360 ipmi:dmi: Base address is zero, assuming no IPMI interface
/dev/sdc2 contains a file system with errors, check forced.
/dev/sdc2:
Inode 131169 seems to contain garbage.

/dev/sdc2: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY.
        (i.e., without -a or -p options)
fsck exited with status code 4
The root filesystem on /dev/sdc2 requires a manual fsck

BusyBox v1.30.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.30.1-4ubuntu6.2) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

(initramfs)
```

Multiple attempts to boot Ubuntu all yielded the same output as shown above.

I did plenty of research (using another computer to search for relevant
web sites, then carefully reading them), and made several attempts to fix
the problem, without success.  I'm hoping that someone is familiar with
this situation, so that they can explain why my Ubuntu 20.04 system is
failing, and can offer a step-by-step procedure to fix whatever is broken.

Ideally, I'll be able to fully restore the system, so that booting it will
lead to the familiar login screen, and all my data will be available.  But
even if Ubuntu is broken and I must re-install it (not a big problem), I
would really like to be able to recover whatever data I can.  I had updated
some files in recent days, and I don't back up my data every time I use the
computer, so I'd hate to lose these recent changes.

To try to fix the problem, I entered "fsck -y /dev/sdc2" at the (initramfs)
prompt (based on advice that I found on several web sites).  Then I entered
"reboot" (at the (initramfs) prompt), but it had no effect, so I entered
"exit".  The screen went blank, and then nothing happened for ~10 minutes,
so I manually powered down the computer.  When I turned the computer back
on and tried to boot Ubuntu, this time the screen displayed the following
two lines:

```
/dev/sdc2: recovering journal
/dev/sdc2: clean, 471037/4890624 files, 6056765/19531250 blocks
```

But then nothing more happened.  So after ~10 minutes, I manually powered
down the computer.  Then I turned it on again, and opted to go into
recovery mode ("Ubuntu, with Linux5.4.0-58-generic (recovery mode)".  Many
lines of output quickly flew past on the screen, and it eventually showed:

```
         Starting GNOME Display Manager...
[***   ] (1 of 2)  A start job is running for Login Service (56s / 1 min 30s)
```

But soon after that, it displayed:

```
[FAILED]  Failed to start GNOME Display Manager.
```

And then it seemed to be stuck in an infinite loop that repeated every
few minutes, first displaying "Starting GNOME Display Manager" and then
displaying "Failed to start GNOME Display Manager".  So I manually powered
down the computer, tried again to boot Ubuntu 20.04 (this time in the
normal way, not recovery mode), and the screen was blank except for the
following two lines near the top (very similar to what I saw before, but
with slightly different numbers):

```
/dev/sdc2: recovering journal
/dev/sdc2: clean, 471039/4890624 files, 6060864/19531250 blocks
```

This time, I just left it to see if anything would happen.  It stayed like
that for over 6 hours, so I gave up, and turned off the computer.

This morning, I tried again to boot Ubuntu 20.04 (in the normal way, not
recovery mode).  As usual, the "GNU GRUB version 2.04" screen appears for a
minute or two, and then automatically disappears.  The screen went totally
blank for ~60 seconds, then briefly displayed "Ubuntu 20.04" in small font
in the center of the screen, and then displayed the following one line of
output at the top of the screen (this time with no mention of "recovering
journal"):

```
/dev/sdc2: clean, 471032/4890624 files, 6064956/19531250 blocks
```

After more than two hours, the screen continues to display only the above
line of output.  A light on the external hard drive occasionally blinks,
which I suppose might indicate that it is doing something (but what?!?).

What do those numbers in the numerators (471032 for files, 6064956 for
blocks) indicate?  And what do the numbers in the denominators (4890624 for
files, 19531250 for blocks) indicate?  Why do they change slightly on each
attempt to boot?  If I leave the computer running, will it make progress
and eventually come to the usual login screen?

Here are some details about my system configuration.  My computer is a Dell
Inspiron laptop with Windows 7 on it, and it's ~8 years old (so somewhat
old, but still quite usable).  I installed Ubuntu 20.04 on a 80 GB partition
that I created on a new Seagate external hard drive (with total capacity 1 TB).
I like having the option to use Windows 7 (it's stable, and supports some
apps that I like) or Ubuntu (a great OS!).  For ~8 years, I've been using
this same arrangement to boot Ubuntu 12.04 from another external hard drive
(never with any problems), so I figured the same procedure should work fine
for Ubuntu 20.04.  When I want to use Ubuntu (20.04, or 12.04), I plug in
the external hard drive to a USB port on the computer, then push the
computer's power button, then hit the F12 key (for Boot Options), and then
select the "USB Storage Device" option.  Then the computer's screen
displays the usual "GNU GRUB version 2.04" screen, and then automatically
proceeds to boot Ubuntu and take me to the login screen (except for when
the filesystem has failed - like the situation I'm in now!).

In case it might help, here are the last lines displayed in the output from
the "fsck -y /dev/sdc2" command (most of the output went flying by so fast
that I didn't have time to read it or make note of it):

```
Free blocks count wrong for group #108 (11074, counted=11124).
Fix? yes

Free blocks count wrong for group #171 (5910, counted=6084).
Fix? yes

Free blocks count wrong (13471083, counted=13474145).
Fix? yes

Inode bitmap differences: -(131169--131184) -(131201--131232) -(131521--131535)
 -(131537--131552)
Fix? yes

Free inodes count wrong for group #16 (82, counted=161).
Fix?  yes

Free inodes count wrong (4419514, counted=4419593).
Fix?  yes

/dev/sdc2: ***** FILE SYSTEM WAS MODIFIED *****
/dev/sdc2: 471031/4890624 files (0.2% non-contiguous), 6057105/19531250 blocks
(initramfs)
```

Before I ran the fsck command, I first entered 'ls' (at the initramfs prompt)
and it displayed the following output (for the various directories under /,
I guess):
dev       bin       init      lib64     sbin      var       tmp
root      conf      lib       libx32    scripts   sys
kernel    etc       lib32     run       usr       proc

I was concerned that I did not see 'home' in that collection.  It makes me
worry that my home directory and everything under it have been lost.

After I ran the fsck command, I entered 'ls' again, and exactly the same
output appeared (with no 'home' in the collection, so I remain very
worried).

Several web pages stated that "fsck -y <failed_partition>" followed by
"reboot" would work, but in my case "reboot" did nothing.  The (initramfs)
prompt merely returned, with no obvious change from before.  So I'm
wondering what prevents Ubuntu from rebooting.

And then when I tried to go into recovery mode, even that failed (because
of the "Failed to start GNOME Display Manager" errors, described above).
So it looks like Ubuntu is in very bad health.

Thank you very much to anyone who can offer helpful information and/or
suggestions.  If you can help me restore my Ubuntu 20.04 installation to
full health, then you will make this holiday season a very happy one for
me.  Or if you can at least help me recover my data, then that would still
be a big help.

Answer (score 1):

The one time that I had this problem, I did not fix it from initramfs, but instead from a bootable USB - You could try that.  Also, There is a `-f` option which you should use for fsck:

`fsck -f /dev/sdc2`

Finally, use `lsblk` to ensure that you are checking all of your block devices.

---

- The `-f` option gets passed to `e2fsck`, and forces a file system check even if the file system reports that it is clean.
- You mention `/dev/sdc2` specifically, so I am assuming there is a `/dev/sdc1`

Comment: Thanks for those tips!

Re "a bootable USB", I currently have the following options:
  1) ubuntu-20.04-desktop-amd64.iso file on DVD-ROM disc (used it to install).
  2) Ubuntu 12.04 on another external hard drive (so it's ~8 years old).
Would either of those work?

Comment: For #1, could I boot from the CD/DVD-ROM tray, choose "test drive" mode, and
open a terminal window for running commands to repair /dev/sdc2?

For #2, I could plug it into another USB port and boot from it.  But would
this old 12.04 version lack any valuable enhancements to the commands (fsck,
etc.)?

I'm not familiar with the 'lsblk' command, but could give it a try.  Will it
assess the health of all partitions on the external hard drive?  And also
look at other disks in the system?

Comment: That hard drive actually has four partitions on it.  The /dev/sdc1 partition
is of size ~56 GB, and hold misc files from the manufacturer.  The /dev/sdc2
bootable partition is of size ~80 GB, and holds Ubuntu 20.04.  The third
partition (size ~20 GB) serves as swap space for Ubuntu.  The fourth
partition (size ~600 GB) serves as an 'Archive' area for backing up
files from Windows 7.  This 'Archive' partition seems to be in good health.

Comment: @JohnKeen Booting from the USB or CDRom in the 'test' mode is exactly what I was referring to.  Sorry I was offline yesterday, how is the health of your disk today?

Comment: Thank you for the follow-up.  Sorry for the delayed response
time from my end.  Today, I finally found a large enough chunk of time to try
your suggestions.  Here is what I did:  
  - Booted from the ubuntu-20.04-desktop-amd64.iso DVD-ROM.  
  - At the "Install" screen, chose the "Try Ubuntu" option .  
  - Opened up a terminal window.  
  - Plugged in the Seagate external hard drive.  
  - Entered the "df" and "lsblk" commands, to confirm /dev/sdc2 is visible.  
  - Entered the "fsck -k /dev/sdc2" command.

Comment: But the output from that fsck command was very ominous (warning me that the
filesystem is mounted, and severe filesystem damage would ensue), so I
answered "no" to abort it.  Should I first enter "umount /dev/sdc2" before
I run the fsck command?  Anything else?

Comment: FYI, here's what happened in that terminal window session:  
`
  ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ fsck -f /dev/sdc2  
  fsck from util-linux 2.34  
  e2fsck 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)  
  /dev/sdc2 is mounted.  
  
  WARNING!!!  The filesystem is mounted.  If you continue, you ***WILL***  
  cause ***SEVERE*** filesystem damage.  
  
  Do you really want to continue<n>? no  
  check aborted.  
  ubuntu@ubuntu:~$  
`
  
What else might I need to do before running fsck?  Thank you for kindly
sharing for your expertise!

Comment: ... sorry for having to post multiple comments, and with suboptimal formatting.  The web site limited the amount of text that I could put in any one comment, and it also stripped away all line breaks.  Sigh.

Comment: @JohnKeen I've not been online in a few days...  The man pages for e2fsck (the actual program being run) indicate that it should be run on an unmounted drive.  As the drive is automatically mounted when plugged in, you would need to unmount the device = `sudo umount /dev/sdc2`